# Property Menu Dissapeared

Tags: interface

While I was making my object, I accidently closed the property menu on the bottom right of the screen. I want to know how to get it back. Im also a beginner at blender and the "How can I reset my menu?" question won't help.

[image]

Comment: Im not really sure, it seems as it is from an older version of blender.

Comment: It's still the same and worth reading.

Comment: If you didn't know, I'm a beginner at Blender and maybe you should simplify it, instead of just thinking I know a lot.

Comment: If you don't know, we all try to help in our spare time. It's not my job to 'simplify' anything for you. Recommend edit your question and explain what exactly "won't work" and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the bottom right hand corner of your asset list (above your version number) and your cursor will turn to a cross

[image]

Once it has changed to this cross, click and drag upwards to open a new panel. You will probably get another panel with your assets listed. Click on the drop down tab highlighted below:
[image]

Now select properties

[image]

This will open a new properties panel in the same place as before